# Django Querying By a Set Relationship (Reverse)

Tags: python, django

I have class called Toy, in which toys are either Animals or Fruits.

Some example from my database,

```
|name|type|pk|
|Jerry|Cat|33|
|Scoobie|Dog|52|
|Leslie|Dog|73|
|Helen|Strawbery|86|
|Mark|Banana|16|
```

When user selects 'Animals', it should output **Jerry, Scoobie, Leslie**, if it selects 'Fruits' it should output **Helen, Mark**.

I need something like below

```
myDict={'Animal':'Cat' or 'Dog', 'Fruits':'Strawberry' or 'Banana'}
Toy.objects.filter(type = myDict[input])
```

or

```
myDict={'Animal':['Cat' ,'Dog'], 'Fruits':['Strawberry' , 'Banana']}
Toy.objects.filter(type in myDict[input])
```

of course they do not work, any ideas how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how your model looks like:

```
Toy.objects.filter(type__in=["Dog", "Cat"])
```

or

```
Toy.objects.filter(type__in=["Strawberry", "Banana"])
```

and thirdly (with all Toy types that is a fruit or an animal)

```
Toy.objects.filter(type__in=["Dog", "Cat", "Strawberry", "Banana"])
```

Since you don't store "animal" as a type according to what you've described you have no need for `{'Animal':[...], 'Fruit':[...]}`.

Comment: ok `type__in` solved, thanks. But still I need the dictionary, anyway not important. I ll accept that answer.

Comment: I must use 15 chars: Why? With the little info you've supplied and the database structure you showed use you have little use for "Animal". Could you post your model, please? That could help me help you.

Comment: well you are saying:   ` if (input=animal) Toy.objects.filter(type__in=["Dog", "Cat"]), else Toy.objects.filter(type__in=["Strawberry", "Banana"])` . That works too, but is there any advantage, than using a dictionary and skipping the if-else?

Comment: Oh you want a dynamic filtering without an if/else?

Comment: No, in your case I think (still without seeing your model) you should go for an if/else. It will serve _this_ usecase better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30317/discussion-between-emmet-b-and-limelights)